# Browser Caching IIS7

Tags: browser, iis-7, caching

Does anyone know how to set up Browser Caching in IIS7 via the web.config file ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Does Jeff's answer in this question help?

[IIS7 Cache-Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642954/iis7-cache-control)