# IIS7 + ASP.NET MVC Client Caching Headers Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, iis-7

I've deployed an ASP.NET MVC app on IIS7 and Windows Server 2008.

I've read posts on here, and around the web, but can't get the darn client-side caching to work.

I'm trying to cache everything in the /Content folder. So far I've select that folder in IIS manager, and set the appropriate HTTP Response Headers (under Common Headers). I've also checked the web.config file in the /Content folder and the values there are being set.

All resources in /Content come back with this (from FireBug):

```
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma        no-cache
Content-Type    image/png
Expires      -1
Last-Modified   Sun, 11 Oct 2009 19:01:40 GMT
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Etag            "f318d643a54aca1:0"
Server        Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Date            Sun, 11 Oct 2009 20:40:01 GMT
Content-Length  620
```

Note the Cache-Control and Expires values for this static image being requested.

The site is currently compiled in Debug (this will change), but surely that wouldn't make a difference?

Obviously I'm overlooking something, any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get it working using the IIS admin tool, try Jeff Atwood's recommendation from 
[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642954/iis7-cache-control):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```