# How can I enable expires headers for my static content in my IIS 6 ASP.NET MVC web app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, web-config, iis-6, windows-server-2003, expires-header

We are running a ASP.NET MVC 2.0 web app and it's running on Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6.0. I understand it would be easy to implement client caching if we [used IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642954/iis7-cache-control). However, that is something I don't have control over. Also, it would probably be very easy to change settings within IIS 6 itself. However, again, I don't have control over that.

What I am looking for is a solution that I can implement within my project itself (web.config perhaps?) that allows me to specify expires headers for static content (JS, CSS, images, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

See this article for how to configure content expiration site-wide:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0fc16fe7-be45-4033-a5aa-d7fda3c993ff.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Sorry I read you have no access to this. I would consider using an httpmodule to add Response-Expires headers to all relevant content