# How to prevent .kml files from being cached on an IIS7 server?

Tags: caching, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, cache-control

Right now the .kml files that I use for a Google Maps implementation on my site are being cached for 7 days because the Cache-Control header within IIS7 is set to 7 days ([as per these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642954/iis7-cache-control)).

I could use version control to update the .kml files when changes are made, but I would rather not because other people might want to refer to them.

Can I configure IIS7, or make a configuration change to the .kml file in order to remove the caching, or set it to a very short period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set/change the expire headers at a per directory basis in IIS.

The easiest way to accomplish what you want is to create a new directory where you serve the .kml files from. Remove the expire headers from that directory.

Comment: Aha! I didn't know you could do that. Thanks :-)