# MVC3 Cache Images Stored in Database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, razor

I am displaying images on my website which I have stored in a database. From my Razor view I write a line such as this.

```
<img alt ="" src='@Url.Action("ShowImage",
            "Controller", new { imageID = Model.ImageID })'/>
```

The function that gets called looks like so.

```
    public ActionResult ShowImage(string imageID)
    {
        WebServiceClient client = new WebServiceClient();
        byte[] image = client.GetImage(Convert.ToInt64(imageID));
        if (image == null)
        {
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
        return File(image,"image/png");
    }
```

This works just fine, but my quesiton is if it is possible to cache these images somehow. I have seen ways to cache images using custom HttpHandler, but all those examples are if you have the actual file and not the binary data.

Comment: Did you try using the build in cache for .NET?

Comment: I've used AppFabric caching for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg457898

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cache rapper you could use:

```
public class CacheManager
{
    private static readonly string keyPrefix = typeof(CacheManager).FullName;
    private static readonly object syncLock = new object();

    private readonly Cache cache;

    public CacheManager(Cache cache)
    {
        this.cache = HttpRuntime.Cache;
    }

    public TValue Get<TValue>(string key)
    {
        return (TValue)HttpRuntime.Cache[MakeKey(key)];
    }

    public void Set<TValue>(string key, Func<TValue> value)
    {
        Set(key, null, null, null, value, null);
    }

    public void Set<TValue>(string key, DateTime timestamp, TValue value)
    {
        Set(key, timestamp, null, null, value, null);
    }

    public void Set<TValue>(string key, TimeSpan duration, TValue value)
    {
        Set(key, null, duration, null, value, null);
    }

    public void Set<TValue>(string key, TValue value, Action<bool> onRemoveCallback)
    {
        Set(key, null, null, null, value, onRemoveCallback);
    }

    public void Set<TValue>(string key, DateTime timestamp, TValue value, Action<bool> onRemoveCallback)
    {
        Set(key, timestamp, null, null, value, onRemoveCallback);
    }

    public void Set<TValue>(string key, TimeSpan duration, TValue value, Action<bool> onRemoveCallback)
    {
        Set(key, null, duration, null, value, onRemoveCallback);
    }

    public void Set<TValue>(string key, IEnumerable<string> fileDependencies, TValue value)
    {
        Set(key, null, null, fileDependencies, value, null);
    }

    public void Set<TValue>(string key, DateTime timestamp, IEnumerable<string> fileDependencies, TValue value)
    {
        Set(key, timestamp, null, fileDependencies, value, null);
    }

    public void Set<TValue>(string key, TimeSpan duration, IEnumerable<string> fileDependencies, TValue value)
    {
        Set(key, null, duration, fileDependencies, value, null);
    }

    public void Set<TValue>(string key, IEnumerable<string> fileDependencies, TValue value, Action<bool> onRemoveCallback)
    {
        Set(key, null, null, fileDependencies, value, onRemoveCallback);
    }

    public void Set<TValue>(string key, DateTime timestamp, IEnumerable<string> fileDependencies, TValue value, Action<bool> onRemoveCallback)
    {
        Set(key, timestamp, null, fileDependencies, value, onRemoveCallback);
    }

    public void Set<TValue>(string key, TimeSpan duration, IEnumerable<string> fileDependencies, TValue value, Action<bool> onRemoveCallback)
    {
        Set(key, null, duration, fileDependencies, value, onRemoveCallback);
    }

    public TValue GetOrCreate<TValue>(string key, Func<TValue> factory)
    {
        return GetOrCreate(key, null, null, null, factory, null);
    }

    public TValue GetOrCreate<TValue>(string key, DateTime timestamp, Func<TValue> factory)
    {
        return GetOrCreate(key, timestamp, null, null, factory, null);
    }

    public TValue GetOrCreate<TValue>(string key, TimeSpan duration, Func<TValue> factory)
    {
        return GetOrCreate(key, null, duration, null, factory, null);
    }

    public TValue GetOrCreate<TValue>(string key, Func<TValue> factory, Action<bool> onRemoveCallback)
    {
        return GetOrCreate(key, null, null, null, factory, onRemoveCallback);
    }

    public TValue GetOrCreate<TValue>(string key, DateTime timestamp, Func<TValue> factory, Action<bool> onRemoveCallback)
    {
        return GetOrCreate(key, timestamp, null, null, factory, onRemoveCallback);
    }

    public TValue GetOrCreate<TValue>(string key, TimeSpan duration, Func<TValue> factory, Action<bool> onRemoveCallback)
    {
        return GetOrCreate(key, null, duration, null, factory, onRemoveCallback);
    }

    public TValue GetOrCreate<TValue>(string key, IEnumerable<string> fileDependencies, Func<TValue> factory)
    {
        return GetOrCreate(key, null, null, fileDependencies, factory, null);
    }

    public TValue GetOrCreate<TValue>(string key, DateTime timestamp, IEnumerable<string> fileDependencies, Func<TValue> factory)
    {
        return GetOrCreate(key, timestamp, null, fileDependencies, factory, null);
    }

    public TValue GetOrCreate<TValue>(string key, TimeSpan duration, IEnumerable<string> fileDependencies, Func<TValue> factory)
    {
        return GetOrCreate(key, null, duration, fileDependencies, factory, null);
    }

    public TValue GetOrCreate<TValue>(string key, IEnumerable<string> fileDependencies, Func<TValue> factory, Action<bool> onRemoveCallback)
    {
        return GetOrCreate(key, null, null, fileDependencies, factory, onRemoveCallback);
    }

    public TValue GetOrCreate<TValue>(string key, DateTime timestamp, IEnumerable<string> fileDependencies, Func<TValue> factory, Action<bool> onRemoveCallback)
    {
        return GetOrCreate(key, timestamp, null, fileDependencies, factory, onRemoveCallback);
    }

    public TValue GetOrCreate<TValue>(string key, TimeSpan duration, IEnumerable<string> fileDependencies, Func<TValue> factory, Action<bool> onRemoveCallback)
    {
        return GetOrCreate(key, null, duration, fileDependencies, factory, onRemoveCallback);
    }

    public void Remove(string key)
    {
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(MakeKey(key));
    }

    private static string MakeKey(string key)
    {
        Check.Argument.IsNotNullOrEmpty(key, "key");

        return keyPrefix + ":" + key;
    }

    private void Set<TValue>(string key, DateTime? timestamp, TimeSpan? duration, IEnumerable<string> fileDependencies, TValue value, Action<bool> onRemoveCallback)
    {
        string fullKey = MakeKey(key);

        lock (syncLock)
        {
            cache.Remove(fullKey);

            InsertInCache(fullKey, value, fileDependencies, timestamp, duration, onRemoveCallback);
        }
    }

    private TValue GetOrCreate<TValue>(string key, DateTime? timestamp, TimeSpan? duration, IEnumerable<string> fileDependencies, Func<TValue> factory, Action<bool> onRemoveCallback)
    {
        string fullKey = MakeKey(key);

        object value = cache.Get(fullKey);

        if (value == null)
        {
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                value = cache.Get(fullKey);

                if (value == null)
                {
                    value = factory();

                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        InsertInCache(fullKey, value, fileDependencies, timestamp, duration, onRemoveCallback);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return (TValue)value;
    }

    private void InsertInCache(string key, object value, IEnumerable<string> fileDependencies, DateTime? timestamp, TimeSpan? duration, Action<bool> onRemoveCallback)
    {
        Action<string, object, CacheItemRemovedReason> raiseOnRemoveCallback = (cacheKey, state, reason) => onRemoveCallback(reason == CacheItemRemovedReason.DependencyChanged);

        cache.Add(key, value, fileDependencies != null ? new CacheDependency(fileDependencies.ToArray()) : null, timestamp ?? Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, duration ?? Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, onRemoveCallback != null ? new CacheItemRemovedCallback(raiseOnRemoveCallback) : null);
    }
}
```

You can now change your code like so:

```
public ActionResult ShowImage(string imageID)
    {
        CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager();
        byte[] image = cacheManager.GetOrCreate(
                    imageID, //Cache Key
                    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), //Will be in Cache for 20 min
                    () => {
                    WebServiceClient client = new WebServiceClient();
                    return client.GetImage(Convert.ToInt64(imageID));
        }); //Delegate to call if the cache is empty

        if (image == null)
        {
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
        return File(image,"image/png");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try decorating your controller action with the [`[OutputCache]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "imageID")]
public ActionResult ShowImage(string imageID)
{
    WebServiceClient client = new WebServiceClient();
    byte[] image = client.GetImage(Convert.ToInt64(imageID));
    if (image == null)
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
    return File(image,"image/png");
}
```

You might also decide where you want those images to be cached using the [Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcachelocation.aspx) property. The default value is `Any` meaning that the output cache can be located on the browser client (where the request originated), on a proxy server (or any other server) participating in the request, or on the server where the request was processed.

Comment: hi Darin sir, i tried as said by [Jeff Atwood](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642954/iis7-cache-control) sir, i am using Web.config to set Expiry for images and css files , but expiry header is not set, it would be great if you could look into the issue. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704618/asp-mvc-expire-headers-not-set-for-static-contents) is my edited question.