# How to cache @font-face in windows server (asp.net c#) web site?

Tags: c#, html, caching, font-face

I have added custom fonts to my website using @font-face, but they reload on each page load/refresh.

In some forums I found a solution about using .htaccess file, but I'm not sure whether I can use it in .net (windows server) or not.

In my web.config file, clientCache is set to Max, but this doesn't affect FONTS.

```
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```

I'd highly appreciate if you give me a sample code or a working solution.

Many thanks in advance!

Kardo

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642954/iis7-cache-control

Comment: @haim770, I already have set the UseMaxAge, but it doesn't affect fonts to get cached.

Comment: Maybe you need to set up a ttf mime map under static content: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IIS7 Cache-Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642954/iis7-cache-control)

Answer (score 0):

While looking for a solution I came across this question. I have a solution and hope it helps others too.

In the comments you have the suggestion [IIS7 Cache Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642954/iis7-cache-control).

What you need to do is,

## 1. Create a web.config file with the below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

## 2. Copy this file to your "fonts" directory and done.

This controls how Web clients and proxy servers will cache the content that IIS 7 and later returns. More information from [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache)

Comment: does this still apply if these sections are in the main root webconfig?

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem so I changed tactic. I couldn't cache TTF (don't know why) but you CAN cache CSS! So I created a CSS file for my font and included it using base64.

Here's an article about it http://blog.patdavid.net/2012/08/embedding-fonts-with-css-and-base64.html

And to convert your font to base 64: http://base64fonts.com/

Comment: See my comment above which refers to http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap