# How to geenrate or customise http headers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, http-headers, azure-storage, imageresizer

I am using AzureReader2 for resizing image that I request from azure blob, resizing is working fine.

Below is my code which is enough for the resizing the image from azure using AzureReader2 plugin

```
<resizer>
    <plugins>
      <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
        <add name="AzureReader2" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxx;AccountKey=xxxxxxx" endpoint="http://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/" />
    </plugins>
  <clientcache minutes="2880" />
  </resizer>
```

But I want to customize http headers like **ETag**, **Last-Modified**, **Cache-Control** options via my webCofig file configuration settings. Which I am feeling difficult to proceed.

So, Any pointers or workaround or leads for generating and customizing the above mentioned options.

Comment: Where is the code you're using?

Comment: As, I am using the plugin there will be only few lines as I showed u in my question in webconfig file to register configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You're using IIS, so use IIS' built-in support for cache control.

See [IIS7 Cache-Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642954/iis7-cache-control)

With disk caching, IIS typically overrides any cache headers ImageResizer sets (like the Expires header set via 'minutes'), so there's not much it can do anyway.